# Where did the system time comes from?

Tags: c++, timer, cpu

I'm so confused about the wall time and system time, how we actually get those time?

For example in some programming language simply execute `GetSystemTime()`, it will return a time represented as microsecond or other formats.

Is it all comes from the CPU counted clock or there exist another piece of hardware handling the time issue?

I don't mean how to get these time, just want to know either it will return the CPU time or a more precise time! It will be great if someone can briefly explain it.

Comment: System Time could be the time since the system was last rebooted or power cycled.

Comment: Your computer contains a precise clock.

Comment: This question is off-topic and will probably be closed, but see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The system contains some kind of [RTC (Real Time Clock)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock).

This is usually an integrated circuit somewhere, sometimes built into another (like a CPU or interrupt controller, for example, anything really). They are usually backed up by a battery so when the system does not have external power, the time continues to tick.

Many RTCs operate using a 32,768 Hz crystal oscillator to keep track of time. That crystal is quartz, hence "quartz watch".

"System Time" could mean the amount of time the system has been powered on. This time could start at zero, and mean "time since system started", or it might start with a copy of the RTC time at boot, and keep track until the system is shut down (and the time is written back into the RTC). This is a timer or clock similar to the RTC, but could be running at a higher frequency, counting smaller amounts of time with each tick. This can give better resolution to software and hardware when time is important.

Comment: Thanks Steve, this question actually raised by my colleagues, they were talking about the timing issue in a product, one of them think CPU time is not quite precise enough since it sometimes get boosted or slowed down, so actually they want to know getSystemTime will always return the CPU time or a more precise time from another hardware.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that API, but a quick check of the documentation doesn't say anything about accuracy. Unless it states how accurate it is, the resolution, etc., there are no guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

`GetSystemTime()` - This is system time using in Windows(Microsoft).

Closely related to system time is process time, which is a count of the total CPU time consumed by an executing process. It may be split into user and system CPU time, representing the time spent executing user code and system kernel code, respectively. Process times are a tally of CPU instructions or clock cycles and generally have no direct correlation to wall time.

Epoch - 1 January 1601 to AD 30,828
Resolution - 1 ms